# React Slide in Sidebar

Tags: css, reactjs, sidebar

I'm trying to make a simple slide in sidebar with React.JS.
The functionality I want to implement is to cover sidebar component with main content component.

I think I added necessary code for this functionality but it does not work. It would be great if anybody can look into my code.. thank you in advance.

React

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
render(){
return(
<div className="sidebar">
 <ul>
   <li>menu1</li>
   <li>menu2</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
)
 }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  isOpen: false
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}

handleClick(){
this.setState({ isOpen : !this.state.isOpen})
console.log(!this.state.isOpen)
}
render(){
let mainStatus = this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
return(
<div className={this.props.mainStatus} id="main" >
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
<div className="main">Main content</div>
</div>
)
}
} 
 class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return(
<div className="container">
    <Sidebar />
    <Main />
</div>
 )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

CSS

```
.container {
display: flex;
}

/**** MAIN ****/
#main {
background-color: #900025;
}

#main.isopen {
left:0;
 background-color:#fff;
}

/**** SIDEBAR ****/
.sidebar {
background-color: #575777;
}
```

Here is [my codepen link](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/brPVvG?editors=0110).

Comment: A little clarification - You want to hide and show the sidebar on the button click. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I implemented Maurice's point. Still button works now but I cannot hide the sidebar yet..  https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/brPVvG?editors=0110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple copy and paste error.

Change:

```
<div className={this.props.mainStatus} id="main" >
```

to

```
<div className={mainStatus} id="main" >
```

In case it was no typing error:
You declare the variable mainStatus as a normal variable in your function and not giving it as a prop to your Main component. So this.props.mainStatus will be undefined.

Tipp: You are not altering the mainStatus variable. I would recommend declaring it as a const to prevent unnecessary bugs, see this for more information:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/282611

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It is working now.  https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/brPVvG?editors=0110